# How to make a stacked bar plot using ggplot to represent soil column/types

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I have my data like this:

```
SampleID  From  To   SampleDepth UnitCode  Gravel_perc Sand_perc Fines_perc
2007-01   0.00 0.2       0.100     Soil          25        70          4
2007-02   0.20 0.4       0.300     Clay          45        45          5
2007-03   0.40 0.6       0.500     Silt          40        50          5
2007-04   1.12 1.2       1.160     Soil          45        10         40
2007-05   2.31 2.5       2.405     Clay          10        30         50
```

I want to make a stacked barplot for the `UnitCode` with respect to the `SampleDepth` using different colours. Example - (0 to 0.2 m -> Soil -> Blue), (0.2 to 0.4 -> Clay -> green), (0.4 to 0.6 -> Silt -> pink) etc. Can anyone please help me in doing this? Also I have provided an image to show what I mean. For different depth intervals ---> different colours to represent the soil type.

Image Example:

[image]

Thank You

Comment: where is the image? also try to put code in code section for better readability. welcome to SO!

Comment: Hi, Sorry its my first time asking a question and things are a little weird. I tried attaching an image but didnt show up. I will try again

Comment: how SampleDepth are grouped?

Comment: The sample depths are the average of From and To. So basically it is the extension's of samples in the ground

Comment: What goes on the x-axis of your graph? Or do you only want a single bar?

Comment: Hi Gregor, I just want a single bar. The y axis is the SampleDepth.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use ggplot? The aqp package has advanced functionality for plotting soil profile data. E.g. see https://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2011/TalkSlides/Contributed/17Aug_1705_FocusV_1-Hydrology_3-Roudier.pdf

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much for your feedback. I didn't know about the aqp package, however it seems really helpful but currently, yes i wanted to accomplish this by using the ggplot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(1), y = -SampleDepth, fill = UnitCode)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("Clay", "Silt", "Soil"),
                      c("darkolivegreen3", "pink", "steelblue2"))
```

[image]

Using this data:

```
dat = structure(list(SampleID = structure(1:5, .Label = c("2007-01", 
"2007-02", "2007-03", "2007-04", "2007-05"), class = "factor"), 
    From = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 1.12, 2.31), To = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 
    1.2, 2.5), SampleDepth = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1.16, 2.405), UnitCode = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Clay", "Silt", "Soil"), class = "factor"), 
    Gravel_perc = c(25L, 45L, 40L, 45L, 10L), Sand_perc = c(70L, 
    45L, 50L, 10L, 30L), Fines_perc = c(4L, 5L, 5L, 40L, 50L)), .Names = c("SampleID", 
"From", "To", "SampleDepth", "UnitCode", "Gravel_perc", "Sand_perc", 
"Fines_perc"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Hi Gregor, thank you very much for your answer. Is there a way we can manually change the colour ? Currently, the colour seems to be generated automatically. It is because I want to give a suitable colour classification to the specific soil types by myself. Thanks

Comment: Updated with colors.

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer. This helps a lot. :-)

Comment: Is there a way of controlling the width of the rectangle (bar), besides adjusting the plotting area?

Comment: @user2955884 sure, see `?geom_bar` and use the `width` argument.

Comment: But that is relative. In my case, the categories (i.e. clay, silt, soil...) are not all present in every barplot to be drawn, and some categories have much longer names than others. As a consequence, the rectangle becomes narrower if the legend becomes wider. I wish to set the width of the rectangle and, in case the legend would become wider, just make wider the size of the plot, keeping rectangles of consisting size. By now I'm just omitting the legend and writing labels on the barplot.

Comment: The `cowplot` package can help with that. See, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13657460/903061) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39719810/903061), or using `gtable` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24333504/903061), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36198587/903061) for aligning plots both ways. If that doesn't answer your question, I'd suggest asking  a new question.

Comment: Thanks. One more: using (standard) textures is very common in soil science and geology, is there any way to add them?

Comment: Search in the [ggplot2] tag for something like "add texture to plot".