# Positioning of grobs

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, grob

I want to plot data for a linear model in a main plot and a plot of the effects (forest plot) as a subplot using `arrangeGrob`.

Here are the data:

```
set.seed(1)
main.df <- data.frame(sample=c(paste("E.plus.A.plus",1:3,sep="_"),paste("E.minus.A.plus",1:3,sep="_"),paste("E.plus.A.minus",1:3,sep="_"),paste("E.minus.A.minus",1:3,sep="_")),
                      replicate=rep(1:3,4),cpm=c(rnorm(12)),
                      factor.level=factor(c(rep("E.plus.A.plus",3),rep("E.minus.A.plus",3),rep("E.plus.A.minus",3),rep("E.minus.A.minus",3)),
                                    levels=c("E.plus.A.plus","E.minus.A.plus","E.plus.A.minus","E.minus.A.minus")))

effects.df <- data.frame(factor.level=c("E.plus.A.plus-E.minus.A.plus","E.plus.A.plus-E.plus.A.minus","E.plus.A.plus-E.minus.A.minus",
                                        "E.minus.A.plus-E.plus.A.minus","E.minus.A.plus-E.minus.A.minus","E.plus.A.minus-E.minus.A.minus"),
                         effect=rnorm(6),effect.df=runif(6,0,0.5),p.value=runif(6,0,1),y=1:6+0.2)
effects.df$effect.high <- effects.df$effect+effects.df$effect.df
effects.df$effect.low <- effects.df$effect-effects.df$effect.df
effects.df$factor.level <- factor(effects.df$factor.level,levels=effects.df$factor.level)
```

The ggplots:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)
require(gridExtra)
main.plot <- ggplot(main.df,aes(x=replicate,y=cpm,color=factor.level))+geom_point(size=3)+
  facet_wrap(~factor.level,ncol=length(levels(main.df$factor.level)))+
  labs(x="replicate",y="cpm")+scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(main.df$replicate))+theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.key=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank(),axis.title=element_text(size=8),plot.title=element_text(size=9,hjust=0.5))
```

Which is:
[image]

```
sub.plot <- ggplot(effects.df,aes(x=effect,y=factor.level,color=factor.level))+geom_point(size=2.5,shape=19)+geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax=effect.high,xmin=effect.low),height=0.1)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=0,linetype="longdash",colour="black",size=0.25)+theme_bw()+theme(legend.key=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank(),axis.title=element_text(size=7),axis.text=element_text(size=7),legend.text=element_text(size=7),legend.title=element_text(size=7))+
  geom_text(aes(x=effects.df$effect,y=effects.df$y,label=format(signif(effects.df$p.value,2),scientific=T)),size=2.5)
```

And is:
[image]

And here's how I try to combine them into a single plot:

```
if(!is.null(dev.list())) dev.off()
blank <- grid.rect(gp = gpar(col = "white"))
sub.plot.grob <- arrangeGrob(blank,sub.plot,ncol=1)
combined.plot <- arrangeGrob(main.plot,sub.plot,ncol=2,widths=c(1,1))
grid.arrange(combined.plot)
```

which gives:
[image]

How do I adjust the position and dimensions so that `sub.plot` is smaller (all layers, e.g., text are reduced proportionally), and is positioned below the legend of `main.plot`?

Comment: Just a quick note. Why do you need the legend for at all? Your variables appear to be well represented by different facets or position on y axis. BTW, have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198451/specify-widths-and-heights-of-plots-with-grid-arrange) and [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend the package `cowplot` for this sort of task. Here, I am building three nested sets (the main plot to the left, then the two legends together at the top right, then the sub plot at the bottom right). Note the wonderful `get_legend` function that make pulling the legends incredibly easy.

```
plot_grid(
  main.plot + theme(legend.position = "none")
  , plot_grid(
    plot_grid(
      get_legend(main.plot)
      , get_legend(sub.plot)
      , nrow = 1
    )
    , sub.plot + theme(legend.position = "none")
    , nrow = 2
  )
  , nrow = 1
  )
```

gives:

[image]

Obviously I'd recommend changing one (or both) of the color palettes, but that should give what you want.

If you really want the legend with the sub.plot, instead of with the other legend, you could skip the `get_legend`.

You can also adjust the width/height of the sets using `rel_widths` and `rel_heights` if you want something other than the even sizes.

As an additional note, `cowplot` sets its own default theme on load. I generally revert to what I like by running `theme_set(theme_minimal())` right after loading it.

Answer (score 1):

here's a grid.arrange solution,

```
grid.arrange(grobs = replicate(4, ggplot(), simplify = FALSE), 
             layout_matrix = cbind(c(1,1), c(3,2), c(4, 2)), 
             widths = c(2,1,1))
```

[image]

with those bits and pieces,

```
get_legend <- function(p) {
   g <- ggplotGrob(p)
   id <- grep("guide", g$layout$name)
   g$grobs[[id]]
}

leg1 <- get_legend(main.plot); leg2 <- get_legend(sub.plot)
gl <- list(main.plot + theme(legend.position = "none"), 
           sub.plot + theme(legend.position = "none"), leg1, leg2)

grid.arrange(grobs = gl, 
             layout_matrix = cbind(c(1,1), c(3,2), c(4, 2)), 
             widths = c(2,1,1))
```

[image]