# R: arrange.grid different plot sizes because of mathematical title notation

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I'm new in designing plots and I've tried constructing barplots with:

```
bar <- ggplot(month1, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=merge1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
bar_f <- bar  + ggtitle("k = 0") + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12, color="gray0"), 
axis.title=element_blank()) 
+ scale_y_continuous(breaks= function(x) unique(floor(pretty(seq(0, (max(x) + 1) * 1.1))))) 
+ scale_fill_manual(values= grp_colors, guide=F) 


bar2 <- ggplot(month2, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=merge2)) + geom_bar    (stat="identity") 
bar2_f <- bar2 + ggtitle(expression(k %in% group("[", "1;12", "]"))) 
+ theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12 , color="gray0"), axis.title=element_blank()) 
+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,3), breaks=seq(3)) + scale_fill_manual(values= grp_colors, guide=F)

combine <- gridExtra::grid.arrange(bar_f, bar2_f, nrow=1, top= textGrob("Monatsdaten: Häufigkeiten", gp=gpar(fontsize=20,font=1)))
```

My problem is, that I've an mathematical notation in my bar2 plot, produced by

```
expression(k %in% group("[", "1;12", "]"))
```

If I would change the title to a "normal" one, the size of the two plots are equal. Obviously the 2nd plot is a bit smaller, caused by the mathematical title. I tried to define outside of the ggplot environment and inside of grid.arrange, but it doesn't work with the expression notation. Is there way to have the same size of the plot objects ?

And another (it's not my main question, but I didn't find an answer) question, can I enlarge the distance between my top title and the plot titles ?

[image]

Comment: maybe try `egg::ggarrange`

Answer (score 0):

Try the `cowplot` package

```
# some plots
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
          stat_summary(geom="bar", fun.y="mean")

p1 <- p + ggtitle("k=0")    
p2 <- p + ggtitle(expression(k %in% group("[", "1;12", "]"))) 

# the plot. Add horizontal alignment
cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, align = "h")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it in grid.arrange ?

Answer (score 0):

grid.arrange has a "heights" option where you can change the size of your plots relative to one another. You would add a term like

```
heights =c(1,1.1)
```

to your grid.arrange call to make the plotted area of your second plot slightly larger. See [Specify widths and heights of plots with grid.arrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198451/specify-widths-and-heights-of-plots-with-grid-arrange) for some examples.